# Joining data frames by a date constraint

Tags: r, merge, frame

I have 2 data frames, the first has an id, a date (Date format) and 2 variables of information, the other one has id, a simulated amount and the creation date (POSIX.ct format) of the simulation. I want to join the 2 data frames together so the variables of information go together with amount and id.

The value of the variables of information depend on the id and the creation date of the variables and the amount. The variables are always created before the amount, therefore the value of the variable that corresponds to the amount has to be that with the latest creation date (which is always sooner than the creation date of the amount), also the id of the simulation and the variables of information must be the same.

I uploaded a picture with an example to make the question easier to understand.

[image: result example]